# Excel IF OR AND Nested Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need logic to choose a certain calculation based on two possible criteria.

The first criteria is:

- If column B = "Partial"
- If columns C and D are greater than 20%
- Then return column E.
- Else If C and D are less than 20 percent then return 1.

The second criteria is:

- If column C and D are greater than 20%
- Then return column E
- Else return column F.

So far I have the following, but I return #VALUE!:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2="Partial",C2>0.2,D2>0.2)),E2,1),IF(OR(AND(C2>0.2,D2>0.2)),E2,F2)
```

Comment: so you return E2 if C2 and D2 are greater than 0.2 regardless of B2 and B2 only decides if you return F2 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF only allows three arguments and you are trying to do more, instead combine them:

```
=IF(AND(C2>0.2,D2>0.2),E2,IF(B2="Partial",1,F2))
```